# Handling different response data types of REST APIs

Tags: python, rest, response, github-api

The requirement for my application is to do a GET on the GitHub API

> https://api.github.com/repos/{full_name}/commits

In the ideal case, this REST API returns a list of dictionaries. Then the application has to fetch the first element of the result.

However, the REST API might also return a dictionary in the non-ideal case(empty repository with no commits). In this case, if the first element is fetched, it will throw a keyerror.

Right now, I have wrapped the code in try..catch. So if an exception is raised in the non-ideal case, the application bails out.

Is there a better way to handle the ideal and non-ideal case?

Comment: Note, that using try/except for flow control is not necessarily frowned upon in the python world and is often considered best practice. If the error case is infrequent in relative terms, don't dismiss the idea of happily using try statements and moving on.

Answer (score 2):

The response for the GitHub API request is in JSON format. It would be better if you parse the response using the JSON library and then use a `for` loop to traverse through the commit data. For example, a good way to print all the commit `sha` that you get from the response can be as follows:

```
import json
import requests

response = requests.get(<<URL with necessary authentication>>)
if response != 0 and response != None:
    response_j = response.json() #here 'response' is the response you get from the requests.get() command for example
    for commit in response_j:
        print(commit['sha'])
```

In case the repository has no commits it should return an empty dict so you can put a condition to check for no commits.

Comment: Will this work if the REST API returns a dictionary in the non-ideal case?

Comment: Oh, you can use an if statement to check empty responses. I have edited the code to include the check.